# call method with stream parameter from stream itself

Tags: java, java-stream

Assume we have the following situation

```
Collection<SomeType> someCollection = ..
Stream<SomeType> stream = someCollection.stream();
methodWithStreamArgument(stream)
```

Is there a stream function to which i can pass a method reference expecting a stream?

for instance:

```
Stream<OtherType> streamHandlingMethod(Stream<SomeType> stream){
  return stream
               .filter(...)
               .map(o -> new OtherType(o))
}

Stream<AnotherType> anotherStreamHandlingMethod(Stream<OtherType> stream){
  ...
}


someCollection.stream()
.call(this::streamHandlingMethod) 
.call(this::anotherStreamHandlingMethod)
```

I would like to be able to wirte it like the latter, so that its a non-nested sequence of e.g map(), filter() etc. that I can express in one statement, instead of having to put the stream into a variable again or configure it ugly like:

```
streamHandlingMethod(someCollection.stream()
 .filter(..)
 .map(..)
 //many other stream returning calls
)
```

Comment: The more important question is probably: why do you want to find such a method?

Comment: Well the stream itself can be a `Stream<Stream<X>>`, so a lot of methods would be applicable.

Comment: @Sweeper so that I can write it in one statement

Comment: You mean like this? `methodWithStreamArgument(someCollection.stream())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exists no such method in the java default libraries. But you could always make your own extension, by wrapping an existing stream in another class.

```
public class MyStream<T> implements Stream<T> {
    private final Stream<T> original;

    public MyStream(Stream<T> original){
        this.original = original;
    }

    // here your own method
    public <V> MyStream<V> call(Function<? super Stream<T>, ? extends Stream<V>> mapper){
        return new MyStream<>(mapper.apply(this));
    }

    // override/implement every method like the following
    @Override
    public MyStream<T> filter(Predicate<T> predicate){
         return new MyStream<>(stream.filter(predicate));
    }

    ...
}
```

This class acts as a Stream, by wrapping every call into an instance of itsself. So when calling the `filter` method, the returned stream from `original` will be enclosed in a new `MyStream` instance.

So you can use it, you'd have to wrap a stream initially, like the following example:

```
new MyStream<>(someCollection.stream())   // wrap with MyStream
    .call(this::methodWithStreamArgument) // execute a call
    .forEach(...);                        // terminal operation
```

Comment: But a standard collection would not return such a custom stream, would it

Comment: @MagnusLutz see the edit. You could also create a `static` methods (like `Stream#of()`) but that would be a design choice